# How to reference AWS managed policy arn in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am going to create an IAM user with cloudformation and need to attach an AWS managed policy `AWSAppSyncInvokeFullAccess`. I think I should use the managed policy like below code:

```
Resources:
  publisherUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      UserName: userName
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - !Ref AWSAppSyncInvokeFullAccess
        - !Ref AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

but it doesn't work since `AWSAppSyncInvokeFullAccess` is from AWS not from this template. What is the correct way to reference the policies?

Answer (score 11):

These are existing AWS-managed policies. So you should use their **full ARN**, which you can get from IAM console:

```
Resources:
  publisherUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      UserName: userName
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSAppSyncInvokeFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

#### Update

Or to make it partition independent:

```
Resources:
  publisherUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      UserName: userName
      ManagedPolicyArns: 
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/AWSAppSyncInvokeFullAccess"
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
```

Comment: [`AWS::Partition`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-partition) psuedoparameter to make it partition-agnostic as well

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone was wondering you can find the ARNs of all IAM policies by clicking on the name of the policy on the Policies page.